# Overriding default django project structure

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Is it possible to override the default project structure in Django?
I'm trying to put all my django apps in a `src` folder but it seems like it is not that easy.
When i try to run my `dev` server, I am getting the error

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_project'".
```

Here is my current project structure

[image]

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError refers to that you haven't installed the module properly. `django_project` isn't a module so your code must have been mistyped. Is it possible that you wrote `import django_project` instead of `import django`?

Comment: I haven't done anything to the code yet. I created the django_project project in Pycharm (for testing purposes), then i created the src folder, and moved django_project inside the src folder. I also created another app inside the src folder.
Do i need to modify something to get this to work?

Comment: how did you run the program?

Comment: with "manage.py runserver" command

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pycharm so I can't help very well.... but I don't think you're supposed to move the folders into src, you're supposed to keep both of them outside of src but in the home folder.

Comment: That's the default, and everything works that way, but i've seen some django projects where the home folder contains mainly the manage.py file and a src folder. I think it is much cleaner this way, and want to change my project structure to be this way, but it has proven to be challenging.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want it to be this way instead of the default other than the aesthetics? As far as I'm concerned, if the default has proven to work, then you should continue to work that way. I'm sorry I couldn't be much help.